# Melhor forma de formatar data em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data

Preciso validar uma função pra pegar 2 meses anteriores da data atual, somente o mm/yyyy.

codigo:

```
function TwoMonthsAgo() {
  const twoMonthsAgo = new Date();
  twoMonthsAgo.setMonth(twoMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 2);
  

  return twoMonthsAgo;
}
```

Comment: `return (1+twoMonthsAgo.getMonth()) + "/" + twoMonthsAgo.getFullYear();`

Comment: No box azul acima sugeri duas perguntas: uma explica como somar meses a uma data (a ideia para subtrair é a mesma, basta trocar o `+` por `-`), e outra explica como formatar (basta adaptar as soluções para o seu formato)

Answer (score -2):

Uma forma simples, lembrando que existem outras:

```
function TwoMonthsAgo() {
    const twoMonthsAgo = new Date();
    twoMonthsAgo.setMonth(twoMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 2);

    let realMonth = twoMonthsAgo.getMonth()+1

    let month = (realMonth < 10) ? "0"+realMonth : realMonth;
    let year = twoMonthsAgo.getFullYear();

    let newDate = month + "/" + year;

    return newDate;
}

console.log(TwoMonthsAgo());
```